# Break Line when throwing exception in caller instead of overridden method

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core, overriding

I have overridden the SaveChanges method in DBContext in order to detect tables with Created/Update information and automatically handle the updating, like so:

```
public partial class MyContext
{
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;

    public MyContext(ITokenService tokenService, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity is ITrackingEntities);
        foreach (var entityEntry in entities)
        {
            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedBy = _tokenService.LoginUserId;
                ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }

            ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedBy = _tokenService.LoginUserId;
            ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However, whenever I write some EF code that throws an exception in my repository tier, the exception line break occurs in my overridden method `SaveChanges()` instead of from the calling repository method, which is making debugging a pain when I call `SaveChanges()` multiple time in a method.

Is there any way to indicate to the debugger not to break the line in my overridden `SaveChanges()` method and rather from a caller of that method?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "get the exception in the overridden method instead of from the caller", and I don't understand what the debugger has to do with it. Can you explain your problem more clearly?  Ideally, write a small, simple, complete program that illustrates the behavior you're talking about that *we* can run in the debugger.

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry for the confusion, I found `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]` which is what I was trying to do. I'm not sure how else to explain it, the debugger line break occurs in my overridden method `SaveChanges()`, but I want the code that called it in my repository tier to line break since you may call `SaveChanges()` multiple times in a single method or sequence of methods.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense. Also, some versions of Visual Studio have a "just my code" feature, which can cause the debugger to, as the name implies, show just your code, and not framework code. You might want to ensure that this feature is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it tends to go, I found the solution 5 minutes after posting the question. For anyone else who needs this sort of functionality, the attribute `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]` is what you're looking for, such that the method I posted becomes:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity is ITrackingEntities);
    foreach (var entityEntry in entities)
    {
        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedBy = _tokenService.LoginUserId;
            ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedBy = _tokenService.LoginUserId;
        ((ITrackingEntities) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This "bubbles up" the exception to the caller so you can more easily debug the issue. However, I would use this sparingly as the method now will report errors away from the custom override.